# Return value from file_operations.write is not respected

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a simple misc device driver for the linux kernel.
In my file_operations.write I do few checks and compare the passed value with a pre defined value, if the value are equal I return the string length, If not I return -EINVAL

The problem is that even that I print the return value before leaving the write, and it is printed in the log as -22, in my client program that I test with I keep getting the count of bytes passed to the write system call. !

Below is a sample from my write function:

```
ssize_t misc_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff,
            size_t count, loff_t *offp)
{
    ssize_t retval;
    pr_crit("count: %zu\n", count);
    pr_crit("strlen(MY_UNIQUE_ID) + 1: %zu\n", strlen(MY_UNIQUE_ID) + 1);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside write \n");
    if (count != (strlen(MY_UNIQUE_ID) + 1)) {
            retval = - EINVAL;
            pr_crit("retval: %i\n", retval);
            goto out;
    }
    if (strncmp(MY_UNIQUE_ID, buff, count))
            retval = -EINVAL;
    else   
            retval = count;
out:   
    pr_crit("retval: %i\n", retval);
    return retval;
}
```

Below is my test client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[] = "0daf007211a9";
    char filename[] = "/dev/misctest";
    int string_size, write_size;
    FILE *handler = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (handler == 0)
    {
            printf("error openning file\n");
            return -1;
    }       
    write_size = fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(char), 2, handler);
    if (write_size < 0)
            printf("Error");
    printf("write_size: %i\n", write_size);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what is printed in the kernel logs:

```
[793868.964583] count: 2
[793868.964593] strlen(MY_UNIQUE_ID) + 1: 13
[793868.964596] Inside write 
[793868.964600] retval: -22
[793868.964602] retval: -22
```

Comment: What program are you using to write to the device file? Can you give an example when you see the above behaviour ? Also, can you paste the values of: count, and the two retval statements that you see from the kernel log?

Comment: I have added more details. Both the program I test with and the kernel logs.

Comment: What is the output of your "client" program?

Comment: FWIW, you can simply use "sudo bash -c echo -n 'yourdata' > /dev/misctest'", or "dd" for testing your misc device driver.

Comment: Also, why are you opening your file in "r+" when you just want to write to it?

Comment: I guess your "if condition in misc_write" is failing and returning -EINVAL, check.                                                     if (strncmp(MY_UNIQUE_ID, buff, count))
    retval = -EINVAL;

Comment: @Amit Thanks for the hint. That's easier than writing a test program for sure. :)

I was opening with "r+" because originally I was testing reading and writing altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing kernel stuff, always use as low level user space api as possible. If you were using `write()` (the system call) everything would be fine (you will get your error code out). But you decided to go with the more complicated `fwrite()` function which does something different (http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite):

> On  success,  fread()  and  fwrite() return the number of items read or
>   written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only  when
>   size  is 1.  If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the
>   return value is a short item count (or zero).
>
> fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers
>   must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

In fact, `fwrite()` could not possibly return a negative value even if it wanted too (check out its signature).

Comment: Good explanation. I guess "if condition in misc_write" is failing and returning "-EINVAL".                                    if (strncmp(MY_UNIQUE_ID, buff, count))
    retval = -EINVAL;

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can get over this, been stuck there for a while.

Sorry for my late response.